# How to add conditions in LATEX macros?

Tags: macros, conditionals

I would like to create custom macros with conditions.
For example, I would like to add an "if-condition" to a macro that I created to write derivatives of any order in relation to a single variable.
Here is the current code of my macro:

```
\newcommand{\df}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\drv}[3]{\dfrac{\df #2^#1}{\df #3^#1}}
```

The first argument *#1* is the order of derivation, the second *#2* the function that we take the derivative and the third *#3* the variable of derivation.
For example,

```
\drv{n}{f}{x}
```

will give

[image]

I would like to change this code so that it don't display the derivation order *#1* if it is equal to 1. But I don't know the syntax, this is why I need your help. I want to write something like

```
\newcommand{\drv}[3]{
      if #1=1
         \dfrac{\df #2}{\df #3}
      else
         \dfrac{\df ^#1 #2}{\df #3^#1}
}
```

Thank you for your help, have a good day.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you. I know but I would like to create my own macros, this is just a simple example to understand the use of conditions.

Comment: There already exist `esdiff`  and `diffcoeff` packages which already can do that (and more: they consider the case of partial derivatives of any order). Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Bernard the OP said this was just a specific example of a more general question about writing macros.

Comment: @Bernard I think the question of the OP goes more in the direction of 'How to create macros with conditions?' The derivative is just an example, so using a package will not help him in this case

Comment: @Bernard thank you for introducing me to these packages. Indeed, I was mainly looking to know how to use "if-conditions", the derivation was only one example.

Comment: In addition to optional arguments, such s provided by @ChistainHupfer's solution, you might be interested in the `ifthen` package, and a series of tests that come with the `etoolbox` package.

Comment: Ok thank, I will get a look to this packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\df}{\mathop{}\!d} % use \mathrm{d} if you really prefer it

\NewDocumentCommand{\drv}{omm}{%
  \frac{\df\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}\kern-\scriptspace}#2}
       {\df#3\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\drv{f}{x}=f'(x),\qquad
\drv[n+1]{f}{x}=\drv{}{x}\drv[n]{f}{x}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `o` an optional argument is denoted; if it is present, `\IfValueT{#1}` will return true and use the argument as shown.

With the given definition, `\df` will behave as expected also in integrals, leaving a thin space before it when necessary.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. I just do not understand the use of `\kern-\scriptspace`.

Comment: @Loïc: `\scriptspace` is the amount of space inserted after a superscript and `\kern<length>` inserts horizontal space. Thus `\kern-\scriptspace` precisely cancels the space inserted between e.g. `d^{n+1}` and `f`.